# i am getting a Cannot GET / error on heroku with express app

Tags: express, heroku, heroku-cli

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.listen((process.env.PORT || 3000), function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
  });

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const scrapers = require('./scrapers');
const db = require('./db')

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // disabled for security on local
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    next();
});

app.get('/answers', async (req, res) => {
    const answers = await db.getAllAnswers();
    res.send(answers)
})

app.post('/answers', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const Ans_data = await scrapers.scraptheweb(req.body.Ans_value)
    console.log({Ans_data});
    const answers = await db.insertAnswer(Ans_data.searchresults_quant, Ans_data.searchresultsq_title,Ans_data.searchresultsq1, Ans_data.Q_url1,Ans_data.searchresultsq2,Ans_data.Q_url2,Ans_data.searchresultsq3,Ans_data.Q_url3,Ans_data.searchresultsq4, Ans_data.Q_url4,Ans_data.searchresultsq5,Ans_data.Q_url5,Ans_data.searchresultsq6,Ans_data.Q_url6,Ans_data.searchresultsq7, Ans_data.Q_url7,Ans_data.searchresultsq8,Ans_data.Q_url8,Ans_data.searchresultsq9,Ans_data.Q_url9,Ans_data.searchresultsq10, Ans_data.Q_url10,Ans_data.searchresultsq11,Ans_data.Q_url11, req.body.Ans_value);
    res.send(answers);
})

//app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))

In My opinion i think here is the error as this is disabled for security on local,
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // disabled for security on local
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    next();
});
```

please suggest me some changes my files are ok the app is running ok on local server but in heroku live server when i checked it this shows can not get so i think the server is looking for the index.html file which he can not find. anyhow i spent a lot of time but cant fixed this so please can anyone solve it thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: function submit_question(){
                const Ans_value = document.querySelector('.question_input').value;
                //send to server
                fetch('http://localhost:3000/answers', { 
                    method:'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({Ans_value})
                })
            }           this function is in index.html

Comment: this is also in index.html               async function Loadanswers(){
                const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/answers');
                const answers = await res.json();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the index file you need to reference it in your routing.

For example something like:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./build/index.html)
})
```

As long as `res.sendFile` references the file that you want to send it should work